# C++/WinRT console application using c++17 language projection

Tags: c++-winrt

I was curious about how I can call .net libraries from a C++ console application using the newer C++/WinRT using C++17 language projections.  But I find that it’s hard to find even a hello world example of this.

How would I create an equivalent console application in C++/WinRT as this simple C# hello world program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace DemoApplication
{
 class Program
 { 
  static void Main(string[] args) 
  {
      Console.Write("Hello World");
      Console.ReadKey();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: *"how I can call .net libraries from a C++ console application"* - You can't. What you can do is call into Windows Runtime Components. Those components can be implemented in any language that can target the Windows Runtime (such as C#). You cannot, however, access arbitrary .NET libraries, such as the BCL. As for a simple "Hello, World!" application, that's almost trivial: `int main() { puts("Hello World"); _getch(); }`. If you can be a bit more specific it's probably just as easy to answer this question, and provide information on a topic that's still poorly understood a decade in.

Comment: Why can’t you just include: “using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::System;”. Then in your code call Console::WriteLine(…); …. That’s what I want to see example of using WinRT

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system?view=winrt-22000

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system?view=net-6.0#classes

Comment: “Windows Runtime Components” are different from “.Net Components”? ?? I guess “RunTime components” are crippled UWP versions of .Net?  They do the same thing just big pieces are missing from UWP that .net has

Comment: Like they didn’t implement System.Console in .net… but they have other .net stuff under System namespace

Comment: *"“Windows Runtime Components” are different from “.Net Components”? ??"* - I don't know what *".Net Components"* are, so, yes, they are probably different things. *"I guess “RunTime components” are crippled UWP versions of .Net?"* - This is conflating lots of different technologies. The UWP is a (restricted) platform that uses the Windows Runtime as its underlying API technology. The Windows Runtime is not confined to the UWP. It is a native programming interface, that's unrelated to .NET.

Answer (score -2):

I guess you need to use c++/cx instead of c++/WinRT, since c++/cx let’s you access .net and c++/WinRT only lets you access the UWP version of .net called runtime components:

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
  System::Console::WriteLine("Hello world");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++/CX, like C++/WinRT, is a native programming language. Neither one has access to the .NET BCL (i.e. everything under the `System` namespace). That's a .NET thing, only. If it appears as a `System::String` in C++/CX, then that is merely a language projection of C++/CX of [`HSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrt/hstring) values. If you need console I/O from a native application, use that native application's libraries (like the raw [console API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions), or C++' I/O streams).

Comment: if it doesn't have access then what the heck is "using namespace System;  and System::Control::WriteLine(....)"??? sure looks like .Net to me...

Comment: granted C++/CX is just a messed up C# compiler with C++ features.. C++/WinRT is a pure C++ compiler with the .net/UWP components wrapped as COM objects in a C++ class?  Except .net/UWP doesn't include a System.Console Class...

Comment: C++/CX can accesss the "BCL" because it is C++ modified to have microsoft languages extensions (CX) that give it C# BSL capibilities... gcref... etc...

Comment: *"if it doesn't have access then what the heck is "using namespace System; and System::Control::WriteLine(....)"???"* - At a guess, this isn't C++/CX, but rather C++/CLI. As such it's not related to the Windows Runtime. *"granted C++/CX is just a messed up C# compiler with C++ features"* - Again, this is wrong. C++/CX is a C++ language extension. Everything compiles down to **native** code. It's a C++ compiler that has WinRT facilities that look like C++/CLI at the source level, but there is not a single bit of .NET in there, at all.

Comment: *"Except .net/UWP doesn't include a System.Console Class..."* - There is no such thing as *".net/UWP"*. The UWP is a **native** platform, that just happens to be easily accessible from .NET. And - as I noted earlier - the Windows Runtime isn't the same as the UWP. If you need access to the console API from a native program that uses the UWP, then simply use the native interface. That can be the console API, or whatever the language support libraries provide (e.g. `printf`, or `std::wcout`).

Comment: *"C++/CX can accesss the "BCL" because it is C++ modified to have microsoft languages extensions (CX) that give it C# BSL capibilities... gcref... etc..."* - This is wrong, again. There is no CLR in the Windows Runtime. Neither C++/WinRT nor C++/CX can directly access the BCL. You're probably thinking of `gcnew`, which is part of C++/CLI. That's a different programming language, targeting a different platform (.NET, specifically).

Comment: As I suspected, this is C++/CLI. The [`#using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-using-directive-cpp) directive does not exist with C++/CX.